# Running a void function in a loop to return a different value every time. How do i store these values since there is no return?

Tags: java, android

I realize the title isn't so clear so i'll explain.
I have a for loop and inside it i am running this function (it is a firebase function and must be void)

```
mstorage.child(img).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String watever = uri.toString();



                    }
                });
```

right now, the string 'watever' contains the value i want (which is a download link to an image).

The problem is i have an ImageView array and i want to use this function to assign a download link to different ImageViews. Because the function is void, i can not simply assign it inside the onSuccess function because it does not recognize my counter. Is there any way to pass the value inside 'watever' so i can use it in my onCreate function, while still maintaining the fact that the the variable is changing on every iteration?

Comment: There is a way to store the value outside, but it's no really advisable. You need to do whatever you want with that uri inside the `onSuccess`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "does not recognise my counter". Where is that counter?

Comment: @theblitz Sorry, should have been more clear. This function is used inside a for loop so the function is being repeated multiple times. It cant access the value of the counter because it is not declared inside the onSuccess function.

Comment: If you declare your counter as an instance variable rather than in the method then you can access it freely within the inner class.

Comment: @theblitz hey can you give me an example of what you mean? this is my first semester programming and im terrible with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class MyClass {

...
....


int myCounter;

private void myMethod(){
    for (myCounter = 0; myCounter < ???; myCounter++){
        mstorage.child(img).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String watever[myCounter] =uri.toString();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Since the counter is an instance variable and not a method variable it is accessible in the inner class without having to be defined as final.

Answer (score 0):

The onSuccess is a callback function, which you have registered to be called after completion of background process. 
Ideally you can access invoking object s members inside it. Adding the following line inside the onSuccess method will help you to populate urlList member of mstorage.

```
mstorage.ulrList.add(watever);
```

Fundamental thing is callback functions are not same as regular functions and their call and return are different.

Comment: Hey thanks. What exactly does urlList do in this case? I mean where does it get stored and how can i access it?

Comment: You declare it as a member in the mstorage class. It should be a List<String> urlList;